# Long elapsed_time with Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-performance

We have been using Azure SQL successfully with low data amounts for some time. Now when we have seen moderate increase in data storage volumes we are experiencing very long query times. What is weird is that querying dm_exec_query_stats shows that the worker/cpu time for queries is very low (roughly 0 seconds) but the elapsed time is long (can be over 30 seconds).

We have upgraded our pricing tier to 100 DTU's after which our resource consumption for all categories is only < 10% of available resources. The execution plans look decent and given that cpu times are so low this shouldn't be an issue.

I have also checked wait times which has yielded no significant results. The wait times for individual queries show just a few milliseconds of wait times and the only significant wait type is SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER which doesn't ring a bell - or exist in Microsoft documentation.

Both the web application and sql server consuming the data are both in Azure West Europe and considering that we have not seen considerable IO amounts it shouldn't be a problem.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this or what is SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER

Comment: What does below query show `select wait_type,
sum(waiting_tasks_count),
sum(wait_time_ms)
 from sys.dm_os_wait_stats
 group by wait_type
 order by sum(wait_time_ms) desc`

Comment: Also can you run  a query and share execution plan as xml

Comment: Can you try updating stats and rebuilding indexes for the tables involved and see if you are facing the same behaviour

Comment: Could you please tell us the specific query or process waits you are seeing using method provided on this article? http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0017.htm

Comment: @TheGameiswar The wait query only shows SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER. Unfortunately cannot share the execution plan but updating stats and rebuilding indices seemed to get the elapsed time and worker time a lot closer together. The difference is still sometimes tenfold but at least it is now only a few seconds instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: We can't just speculate things with out looking at more details..